# Logical issue in application code - total sum isn't correct

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am not even sure what I am doing is possible.
Do `switch` `case` statements and `if` `else` statements not play well together?

The requirement of my program is:

- First ask user for a screen size. If screen size is equals to 13.3, add $200 to the laptop price. If screen size is equals to 15.0 - add $300 to the laptop price. If screen size is equals to 17.3 - add $400 to the laptop price.
- Ask the user for the CPU type. If CPU type equals to i3, add  $150 to the laptop price. If CPU type equals to i5, add $250 to the laptop price. If CPU type equals to i7, add  $350 to the laptop price.
- Ask the user for the RAM size. Add $50 for every 4GB of ram to the laptop price. Then, ask user for storage type. There are 2 options: SSD and HDD. If it's HDD - add $50 to the laptop price for every 500gb.  If it's SSD - add $100 to the laptop price for every 500GB.
- Ask the user for for the screen resolution. There are 2 options, FULLHD and 4K. Add $100 if it's FULLHD screen and $200 if it's 4K screen.

---

Any help on making my code more readable or any other tips you guys can give me are greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class laptopConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String screenSize = "";
        String cpu = "";
        int ram = 0;
        String storageType = "";
        String screenResolution = "";
        int memorySize = 0;
        double total= 0.0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Select screen size:");
        screenSize = scan.next(); 
        switch(screenSize){

            case("13.3"):
            total += 200;
            break;

            case("15.0"):
            total += 300;
            break;

            case("17.3"):
            total += 400;
            break;

            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }

        System.out.print("Select CPU type:");
        cpu = scan.next();
        switch (cpu){

            case("i3"):
            total += 150;
            break;

            case("i5"):
            total += 250;
            break;

            case("i7"):
            total += 350;
            break;

            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }

        System.out.print("Select RAM size:");
        ram = scan.nextInt();
        total = total + ram * 50;

        System.out.println("Select storage type:");
        switch(storageType){

            case "SSD":
            storageType = "SSD";
            break;

            case "HDD":
            storageType = "HDD";
            break;

            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter memory size:");

        memorySize = scan.nextInt();

        if (storageType.equals("SSD")){
            memorySize = memorySize * 100;
            total = total + memorySize;
        }else if (storageType.equals("HDD"));
            memorySize = memorySize * 50;

        total = total + memorySize;

        System.out.println("Enter screen resolution");
        screenResolution = scan.next();
        if (screenResolution.equals ("FULLHD")){
            total = total +100;
        }else if (storageType.equals("4K"));
            total = total +200;

        System.out.println("Laptop price is: "+ total);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact error do you have?

Comment: "Select screen size:13.3
Select CPU type:i7
Select RAM size:8
Select storage type:
Invalid choice <---------- Run Through
Enter memory size:
100
Enter screen resolution
4k
Laptop price is: 6150.0"

Comment: @Malice9c  Are you stuck in an error?  Is the program compiling successfully? We need the exact ask from you, in order to help you accurately.

Comment: I am having a logical error. it compiles sucessufull but runs throught the Select Storage block to print "Invalid choice". I give an input to "select RAM size" and it just prints "select Storage type: invalid choice" without input . Then skips to the next line "enter memory size".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String storageType = "";
```

You never re-assign `storageType` prior to its usage

```
System.out.println("Select storage type:");
switch (storageType) {
    case "SSD":
        storageType = "SSD";
        break;
    case "HDD":
        storageType = "HDD";
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
}
```

The `default` branch will always be taken (does this `switch` have any sense at all?)

```
System.out.println("Invalid choice");
```

and subsequent operations using that variable won't be correct, for example

```
if (storageType.equals("SSD")) {
    memorySize = memorySize * 100;
    total = total + memorySize;
} else if (storageType.equals("HDD")) {
    ;
}
```

Both branches will be skipped, and the final price will be wrong.

Comment: This means that YOU NEVER ASK for the Storage Type like you did on Screen Size and CPU and such. Add "storageType = scan.next()"

Comment: Thank you! That was it, (other than my math being off).

Comment: @Malice9c advice: when you're stuck on this kind of problems, stop a minute, go away from the computer, than come back and read it from top to bottom

Answer (score -2):

You need add boolean flags and wrap your menus in `while` loops. Note: I'm writing this on my phone, so I don't have your code in front of me.

```
Boolean validRam = false; // same for screen size, etc.
while(!validRam) {
  // same code as normal
  switch(choiceRam) {
  case "16":
    totalCost +=250;
    validRam = true; // <--- this line
    break;
  case "32":
   // etc
  }
}
```